# File upload script returning false

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a script that allows users to change their profile picture for a website that I am making. Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
        <form action="upload_prof_pic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" name="file" id="file" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload Profile Picture" />
        </form>
```

Here is the PHP code for upload_prof_pic.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("includes/connect.php");

$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION["logged_in"]."'");
$rows = $results->fetch();

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (
    (
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    )
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        //error: uploading
        header("Location: account.php?err=upload");
    } else {
        //success
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "prof_pic/users/".$rows["username"]."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $db->query("UPDATE users SET prof_pic='".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION["logged_in"]."'");
        header("Location: account.php");
     }
} else {
    //error: invalid file
    header("Location: account.php?err=invalid");
}

?>
```

It always runs the '//error: invalid file' part of the script. Can anyone help? It worked once, then I changed something in the '//success' part. This shouldn't have had any effect, but apparently it did.

Comment: Simply put, one of your checks is failing. Why don't you run the following before the `if` statement ~ `var_dump($_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $extension); exit;`

Comment: or just `print_r($_FILES);` get the whole lot

Comment: @Phil Thank you! It turns out I had my size set too low. I set it higher, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

i got that same error so i used following javascript coding.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-func.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateFileUpload() {
        var fuData = document.getElementById('filename');
        var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

//To check if user upload any file
        if (FileUploadPath == '') {
            alert("Please upload an image");

        } else {
            var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(
                    FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

//The file uploaded is an image

if (Extension == "gif" || Extension == "png" || Extension == "bmp"
                    || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg") 

            {


             <?php
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "prof_pic/users/".$rows["username"]."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $db->query("UPDATE users SET prof_pic='".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION["logged_in"]."'");
        header("Location: account.php");
?>
            } 

//The file upload is NOT an image
else {
                alert("Photo only allows file types of GIF, PNG, JPG, JPEG and BMP. ");

            }
        }
    }
```

html part

```
<input onchange="ValidateFileUpload(this);" type="file"  name="file"  id="filename"/>
```